# Elapsed event for the time not working, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, timer

I am using a timer to output text to textbox every 2 seconds. but it seems that it doesnt work. any idea what is wrong. here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public void BtnGenData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

      // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
      aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

      // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
      aTimer.Interval = 2000;
      aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      string GenData = "Welcome";
      Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
      frm1.TboxData.AppendText(GenData.ToString());
    }
}
```

Actually i dont see any output coming.

Comment: You need to use `AutoReset` property, and to `Start` your timer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx
(Answers from @Ondra and @Habib below are right too, but this is not the reason why nothing happens with your actual code.)

Comment: @psycho , i didnt use  `AutoReset` , but i started the timer normally. i will give a try the  `AutoReset`.. thnks

Comment: It's not necessary, but if you want your event to be fired "every 2 seconds" until you stop the timer, it's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not straightly connected with the problem you have in your code, but...

From MSDN [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

> The server-based Timer is designed for use with worker threads in a
>   multithreaded environment.

In Windows Forms you can use [System.WindowsForms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx):

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }

    public void BtnGenData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BtnGenData.Enabled = false;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        BtnGenData.Enabled = true;

        //do what you need
    }
```

---

As for your code, why make the timer static? Try to use this:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public void BtnGenData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

     public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
        this.TboxData.AppendText("Welcome");
     } 
 }
```

Also you should take into consideration, what could happen if you pressed the button twice...

Comment: Even `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` needs a call to `Start()` ;)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, thanks. you first way works fine. but i had to remove the "stop timer" to get an output every 2 seconds.. anyway thanks alot.

the second way u mentioned, i am not sure why i was using static, i thinks i shouldnt use it. i will try the non-static method and see what happens. thanks

Comment: @Liban, this `timer.Stop();` made the timer work only once, so if that behaviour is not what you need, you need to put this code somewhere else...So you're right, but don't forget to stop the timer some day:))

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this method:

```
public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{


    string GenData = "Welcome";
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.TboxData.AppendText(GenData.ToString());

}
```

By calling `new Form1();` you create a new form. This form is created as hidden, you change the text, but it is not displayed and at the end of this method it is garbage collected. What you want is to reuse your existing one. Completely remove this line and use your existing form. By default the name should be `form1`

```
public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{


    string GenData = "Welcome";
    form1.TboxData.AppendText(GenData.ToString());

}
```

Comment: if i remove the line u mentioned i will get this error 'error CS0103: The name 'frm1' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: @Liban You need to know the name of your existing form - by default form1

Comment: Also as @Konstantin Vasilcov pointed in the answer bellow, don´t use static timer and elapsedMethod

Comment: the default is form1, but as long as the method is static, "form1" will not exist in the method. when i used non-static method it worked.. thanks for pointing out that one..